# Any command to help export multiple mailboxes in Exchange 2010?

Tags: exchange-2010, mailbox

Any command to help export multiple mailboxes in Exchange 2010? I'm not exporting all the mailboxes but I was wondering if you had any useful tip to make the process faster and easier.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where are you exporting these to? Is this to another exchange server or to storage?

you couold do this via PowerShell and using a pipe for each mailbox and then run the script.

Comment: Thank you for the answer T1nt1n :) sorry for the late response but I went on holidays ^^